# Flutter - Bind form to model

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-reactive-forms

I'm using [reactive_forms](https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms) in Flutter which is a model-driven forms library which takes inspiration from Angular Reactive Forms.

It is fairly simple, to add a form with one formControl called 'nickName':

```
  final _form = FormGroup({
    'nickName':
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
  });
```

My question is, isn't it commonly done and good practice to have the form control "nickName" be bound to a property of a domain model? As this is what is done in another codebase that I have worked on in Angular.

I do have a domain model for this form (although it has more fields than the form contains. The rest of the fields are set in forms on the following pages - like a setup wizard):

```
class UserRegistrationEntity {
  String nickName;
  String email;
  String confirmEmail;
  String password;
  String confirmPassword;
}
```

I can create the model like so:

```
final userRegistration = UserRegistrationEntity();
```

But how can I now bind the `nickName` field of `userRegistration` to my form control? I was expecting the form library to have an equivalent to `ngModel` field for me to set the field of my model on a form control.

Or is this just not something that is done in Flutter?

example: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my use with `reactive_forms` in flutter, I have **NOT** seen any equivalent to `ngModel`. This is because elements like `ReactiveTextField` are designed with double-binding capability with widgets (two-way binding)

That's why you don't include properties like `onChanged`, which would be similar to the ngModel method `#ngOnChanges()`

So, to bind the nickName field of userRegistration to your form control, you would make use of a `ViewModel` and `Provider`.

So  your code would look like this:

```
class YourViewModel {
   final _form = FormGroup({
    'nickName':
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required]),
  });

//assuming you are signing in
void signIn() {
    final credentials = this.form.value;
    //the rest of your signIn code
  }

}
```

```
class YourScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final viewModel = Provider.of<YourViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    return ReactiveForm(
      formGroup: viewModel.form,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ReactiveTextField(
            formControlName: 'nickName',
          ),
          ReactiveFormConsumer(
            builder: (context, form, child) {
              return RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Submit'),
                // if the form is valid, sign-in or whatever you need to do with the form data (I have used signIn)
                onPressed: form.valid ? viewModel.signIn : null,
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**CONCLUSION**

ngModel is a directive which binds input,Reactive Forms does the same and maintains separation between views and model, while still sustaining data synchronization. There is, therefore **NO** apparent need to bind your data to the domain layer, instead `reactive_forms` removes the need to do that entirely, because that *process* is built in.

Answer (score 2):

Update 2022 - [reactive_forms_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms_generator) is released. It's a code generator for [reactive_forms](https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms). It generates a lot of form functionality; one example is that it binds a strongly typed model to the form. It has a FormModel:

```
abstract class FormModel<TModel> {
  FormModel({required this.form});
  final FormGroup form;
  TModel get model;
}
```

And `form` and `model` are in sync (`model` is a getter that returns the strongly typed model by retrieving each form value).